# How use IdCompressZlib component with CBuilderXE

Tags: c++builder, indy, indy10

I need to use the IdCompressZlib component with CBuilderXE, 
but I didn't find documentation or examples on that subject.
I also make some experimantal attempt to use it which failed.

Can someone post me some example on how use thsi component or some usefull lik for such topic ?

**Update:** Belowe a sample code I have tryed , and which give the errore -5 when the method InflateStream is called:

```
    int err;
String Fun = "[TestCompress] ", s1, zipString, strTest = "The 'zlib' compression library provides in-memory compression \
 and decompression functions, including integrity checks of the uncompressed data. \
 This version of the library supports only one compression method (deflation) \
 but other algorithms will be added later and will have the same stream interface. ";

TStringStream * inpStream = NULL, *outStream = NULL;
TMemoryStream * stream1   = NULL, *stream2 = NULL;

stream1 = new TMemoryStream();
stream2 = new TMemoryStream();

inpStream = new TStringStream();
outStream = new TStringStream();

inpStream->Clear();
inpStream->WriteString(strTest);
stream1->LoadFromStream(inpStream);
stream1->Position = 0;

IdCompressorZLib1->InflateStream(stream1, stream2);

outStream->Clear();
stream2->SaveToStream(outStream);
zipString = outStream->DataString;

MyLog(Fun + Format("Compress test: Compress size from [%d] to [%d]",
        ARRAYOFCONST((strTest.Length(), zipString.Length()))));
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? What have you tried so far that did not work for you? What are you trying to use `TIdCompressorZLib` for exactly?

Comment: Hi Remy, my first trouble is the lack of documentation about the component, so an example can give me a lot of help.

I made some simple test in order to compress a string inside a stream.

Comment: The last attempt was the following and always I have ann error Z_DATA_ERROR (-3) when I call InflateStream method.

Comment: '
 TStringStream * inpStream = NULL, *outStream = NULL;
 TMemoryStream * stream1 = NULL, * stream2 = NULL;

 stream1 = new TMemoryStream( );
 stream2 = new TMemoryStream( );

 inpStream = new TStringStream(strTest);
 stream1->LoadFromStream(inpStream);

 outStream = new TStringStream(zipString);

 IdCompressorZLib1->InflateStream(inpStream, stream2 );   << -- Z_DATA_ERROR(-3) HERE  

 stream2->SaveToStream( outStream );
 zipString = outStream->DataString();

 MyLog(Fun + Format("Compress test: Compress size from [%d] to [%d]",
   ARRAYOFCONST((strTest.Length(), zipString.Length()))));
  '

Comment: I have to corrige myself, the error I get is not -3 but -5 (Z_BUF_ERROR)

Comment: You are probably encountering something related to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/indyproject/issues/detail?id=197) or [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/indyproject/issues/detail?id=198). They haven't been fixed yet. And next time, please update your original question with code, don't put it in comments.

Comment: I'm sorry for the unformatted code, but I didn't want to put the atention on my wrong code, but aske if someone ha some simple example that show me how conpress a string sInput and save the compressed data in another string sOutput.
Do you have some example like the one I looking for ?

Comment: After calling `stream1->LoadFromStream()`, `inpStream->Position` is at the end of the stream.  You are not resetting it back to 0 before passing `inpStream` to `IdCompressorZLib1->InflateStream()`, so it will not have anything to process.

Comment: Now I resetted position to 0 and I get back to error -3 when I call InflateStream

I try another solution using the implentation of Zlib for XE made by www.base2ti.com 
It simply works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not decompress a simple string!
error: (-5) `InflateStream` looks at the first to bytes must be: `zlib: 78 01 or 78 9C or 78 DA`
error: (-3) `InflateStream` found the first to bytes (78 01) but the length did'nt match.
in your strTest the first to bytes are "Th".

try it with the following code (tested with Rad 2010 Indy10)

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{

String strTest = "The 'zlib' compression library provides in-memory compression \
 and decompression functions, including integrity checks of the uncompressed data. \
 This version of the library supports only one compression method (deflation) \
 but other algorithms will be added later and will have the same stream interface. ";

TStringStream * inpStream = NULL;
TMemoryStream * stream1   = NULL, *stream2 = NULL, *stream3 = NULL;

stream1 = new TMemoryStream();
stream2 = new TMemoryStream();
stream3 = new TMemoryStream();

inpStream = new TStringStream();


inpStream->Clear();
inpStream->WriteString(strTest);
stream1->LoadFromStream(inpStream);
stream1->Position = 0;

// first compress stream1 with Level 1
IdCompressorZLib1->DeflateStream(stream1,stream2,1);

stream2->SaveToFile("test.dat");
stream3->LoadFromFile("test.dat");
stream2->Position = 0;
// Now decompress stream3
IdCompressorZLib1->InflateStream(stream3,stream2);
stream2->SaveToFile("test2.dat");

}
```

After running the program there are 2 files in the debug folder **test.dat** and **test2.dat**

test.dat a few bytes (size 190)

```
xUQnÃ0C¯Â¿¶@× ... (Hex 78 01 55 8F 51 6E C3 ...)
```

test2.dat a few bytes (size 306)

```
The 'zlib' compression library provides in-memory compression  and dec ...
```

Comment: You are right moskito. I used the Inflate and Deflate function in the wrong order.  The lack of manuals led to to a wrong intepretations of the functions meaning.  Tanks.

Answer (score 0):

Belowe you will find the working sample
Thanks everyone for the suggestions

```
void __fastcall TFormMain::btnTestIdCompressClick(TObject * Sender)
{
    int err;
    String Fun = "[TestIdCompress] ", s1, zipString, strTest = "The 'zlib' compression library provides in-memory compression \
     and decompression functions, including integrity checks of the uncompressed data. \
     This version of the library supports only one compression method (deflation) \
     but other algorithms will be added later and will have the same stream interface. ";

    TStringStream * inpStream = NULL, *outStream = NULL;
    TMemoryStream * stream1   = NULL, *stream2 = NULL;

    try
    {
        MyLog("--------------------------------------");
        MyLog(Fun + Format("Original msg : size=[%d] data=[%s]", ARRAYOFCONST((strTest.Length(), strTest))));

        stream1 = new TMemoryStream();
        stream2 = new TMemoryStream();

        inpStream = new TStringStream();
        outStream = new TStringStream();

        inpStream->Clear();
        inpStream->WriteString(strTest);
        stream1->LoadFromStream(inpStream);
        stream1->Position = 0;

        IdCompressorZLib1->DeflateStream(stream1, stream2, 1);

        outStream->Clear();
        stream2->SaveToStream(outStream);
        zipString = outStream->DataString;

        MyLog("--------------------------------------");
        MyLog(Fun + Format("Compressed msg : size=[%d] data=[%s]", ARRAYOFCONST((zipString.Length(), zipString))));

        inpStream->Clear();
        inpStream->WriteString(zipString);
        stream1->LoadFromStream(inpStream);
        stream1->Position = 0;

        stream2->Position = 0;
        // Now decompress stream3
        IdCompressorZLib1->InflateStream(stream1, stream2);
        outStream->Clear();
        stream2->SaveToStream(outStream);
        s1 = outStream->DataString;
        MyLog("--------------------------------------");
        MyLog(Fun + Format("Decompressed msg : size=[%d] data=[%s]", ARRAYOFCONST((s1.Length(), s1))));

    }
    __finally
    {
        if (stream1)
        {
            stream1->Clear();
            delete stream1;
            stream1 = NULL;
        }
        if (stream2)
        {
            stream2->Clear();
            delete stream2;
            stream2 = NULL;
        }
        if (inpStream)
        {
            inpStream->Clear();
            delete inpStream;
            inpStream = NULL;
        }
        if (outStream)
        {
            outStream->Clear();
            delete outStream;
            outStream = NULL;
        }
    }

}
```